# Import Error In Python

Tags: python-2.7

when I try to import some class form other package in Python, It would always pop up the error: No module named ...

Attached is my directory structure and debug error. Could anyone take a look and find out the route cause of the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your error message is **text**. Please copy that text in your question as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
from Lib import myclasss
```

Also please check your class name and file name. Your file name is `myclass.py` but you are importing `myclasss` .

Comment: Thanks Pratik. It's maybe I type save shortcut add a "s" at the end of "myclass", But can you see line 3 which I have commented. It's use the way you mentioned.it would pop up error "    from Lib import myclass
ImportError: No module named Lib"

Comment: You then need to add path of lib for python to search on. Use this
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.join("Lib"))))

Comment: Then, Can I know the route cause of the issue? if I add another package, still add the path this way?

Comment: Your python can only search for modules in predefined paths which are lib or your current directory etc. Here you are importing module from another directory which not in the path of python so it will not search for the modules in that directory. You have to tell python specifically to add this new directory to its searchable paths.

Answer (score 0):

@Pratik Gujarathi is right make sure that your class name is right. If it doesn't work post fixing the class name, try manually adding the current class path to system path using the following piece of code

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.join("Lib"))))
```